# How do i reset the value of a lablel to the previous value, after changing it with a checkbox VB

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

I am trying to add 10% insurence per passenger when chkInsurence is checked, and when it gets unchecked to return it to the same value. here is my code

```
Private Sub chkInsurance_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkInsurance.CheckedChanged
    If chkInsurance.Checked Then
        price += CDec(price * 0.1) * nudPassengers.Value
    Else
        price -= CDec(price * 0.1) * nudPassengers.Value
    End If
    lblPrice.Text = price.ToString("C")
End Sub
```

When the Else runs it takes 10% of the current value and subtracts that instead of 10% of the original value.

Comment: `nudPassengers.Value.ToString` ??

Comment: Instead of modifying `price`, declare another variable called `TotalCost`?

Answer (score 0):

you may store the value of the label of price in a variable and when user unchecks, assign stored value to the label

Answer (score 0):

I modified another variable instead of price like Idle_Mind suggested thanks

Private Sub chkInsurance_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
chkInsurance.CheckedChanged

```
    Dim insurenceTotal As Decimal
    If chkInsurance.Checked Then
        insurenceTotal = CDec(price + (price * 0.1) * nudPassengers.Value)
        lblPrice.Text = insurenceTotal.ToString("C")
    Else
        lblPrice.Text = price.ToString("C")
    End If
End Sub
```